# Request All Charges from Stripe - Promise error

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm struggling to return all charges from Stripe with the node package without running into a promise error.

Obviously this is competent outside the control of the developer, so I can't provide things that I've tried. The call is direct from the docs and uses the recommended package.

This is happening both in the local environment and when hosted at Heroku.

It seems suceed for a while before the error occurs, which points to rate limiting, but Stripe have ruled that out as it would return a specific error.

```
stripe.charges.list(
  { limit: 70000},
  function(err, charges) {
//other stuff 
  }
);
```

Please note that without the limit parameter, the same issue exists - around 10,000 records are returned before the error.

Node: 10.15.1
Stripe "6.31.2
 timestamps of the failed requests
 full stack trace of the error

> 2019-05-08T17:04:25.891410+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:36) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: An error occurred with our connection to Stripe.
>   2019-05-08T17:04:25.891426+00:00 app[web.1]: at Constructor._Error (/app/node_modules/stripe/lib/Error.js:12:17)
>   2019-05-08T17:04:25.891427+00:00 app[web.1]: at Constructor (/app/node_modules/stripe/lib/utils.js:139:13)
>   2019-05-08T17:04:25.891428+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Constructor (/app/node_modules/stripe/lib/utils.js:139:13)
>   2019-05-08T17:04:25.891431+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:218:9
>   2019-05-08T17:04:25.891435+00:00 app[web.1]: at ClientRequest. (/app/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:426:67)
>   2019-05-08T17:04:25.891437+00:00 app[web.1]: at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:189:13)
>   2019-05-08T17:04:25.891438+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:426:9)
>   2019-05-08T17:04:25.891440+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:194:15)
>   2019-05-08T17:04:25.891441+00:00 app[web.1]: at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1125:12)
>   2019-05-08T17:04:25.891442+00:00 app[web.1]: at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
>   2019-05-08T17:04:25.891581+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:36) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   2019-05-08T17:04:25.891654+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:36) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code

Comment: The `limit` parameters only [supports values from 1 to 100](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list#list_charges-limit). It's recommended that you use [auto-pagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto) instead.

Comment: Thanks @taintedzodiac - However to note I also get this error with no `limit` param in place, and can return around 10,000 charges before the error.

Comment: Thanks for following up on that! It does indeed sounds like a connection issue -- could be rate limiting since you're retrieving so many results. Could you try auto-pagination and see if that helps?

Comment: @taintedzodiac Thanks again, you read my mind, however I asked Stripe this and they suggested rate limiting would throw its own error, and ruled it out. I tried Stripe's autopaging each and sadly got the same result after around 11,000 records.